# 100vh на мобильном: совместить код при событии resize

Tags: javascript, css, frontend

В [записи](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/) на CSS-Tricks есть код для коррекции размера vh на мобильном с событием resize:

```
// First we get the viewport height and we multiple it by 1% to get a value for a vh unit
let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
// Then we set the value in the --vh custom property to the root of the document
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);

// We listen to the resize event
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // We execute the same script as before
  let vh = window.innerHeight * 0.01;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--vh', `${vh}px`);
});
```

В комментариях пользователь описал [проблему](https://css-tricks.com/the-trick-to-viewport-units-on-mobile/#comment-1651291) при использовании кода с resize – происходит скачок фонового изображения на первом экране при скролле страницы.

Там же есть код для решения этой проблемы:

```
var root = document.documentElement;
if (
    window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ||
    Math.abs(this.lastHeight - window.innerHeight) > 100
) {
    root.style.setProperty(`--window-vh`, window.innerHeight + 'px');
    this.lastHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
```

По словам автора, как я понял, код обновляет vh только при значительном изменении высоты экрана устройства и предотвращает скачок.

Как совместить этот код с основным с resize?